# Marginal distributions of off-diagonal terms in a Wishart-distributed random variable

Tags: covariance, marginal-distribution, wishart-distribution

I am interested in finding expressions for the marginal distributions of the off-diagonal terms in a Wishart-distributed random variable.

More specifically, suppose $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix, each row of which is independently drawn from a $p$-variate normal distribution with zero mean:
$X_{(i)}{=}(x_i^1,\dots,x_i^p)^T\sim N_p(0,V)$. Then $S=X^T X$ is a Wishart-distributed random variable, denoted $S\sim W_p(V,n)$.

Expressions exist for the marginal distributions of the diagonal terms, $S_{i,i}$ (e.g., page 4, third bullet point in [this](http://www.stat.duke.edu/~km68/materials/214.9%20%28Wishart%29.pdf) document). But I haven't been able to find similar expressions for the off-diagonal marginal distributions, $S_{i,j}$, where $i \neq j$.

Do they exist and, if so, what are they?

Comment: I wonder if you can rotate the problem away. That is, consider the distribution of $QSQ^{\top}$ for orthonormal $Q$, where you have somehow rotated an off diagonal onto a diagonal?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer to this can actually be found on [the wikipedia article about the Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Marginal_distribution_of_matrix_elements), which indicates that it is [variance-gamma distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-gamma_distribution).